# How does cvSeqPush work?

Tags: c, visual-c++, opencv

I am creating an application where I need to push some element in the sequence, I am using `cvSeqPush`, but I am not getting its second argument `const void * element`, I need to push a point of type `cvPoint`.

How is this done in C?

Comment: Can you give a snippet of the code you've tried so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is called to push on the sequence whatever data you have, but in your case as I guess your sequence is configured to contain CvPoints's you will have to point to that kind of data to have a correct program.

```
CvPoint pnt = cvPoint(x,y);
cvSeqPush(srcSeq, (CvPoint *)&pnt);
```

Something like this should work for you, just point to some data the sequence needs.
If you need something more specific to your case you should post some code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things need to be added:
1.  you will need to allocate memory to store your srcSeq
2.  release memory when you're done using srcSeq

CvMemStorage* srcSeq_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

CvSeq* srcSeq = cvCreateSeq(0, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(CvPoint), srcSeq_storage);

// now push your point element to srcSeq

cvSeqPush(srcSeq,&pnt);

// don't forget release memory

cvReleaseMemStorage(&srcSeq_storage);